# Date based search on two tables in two different DBs

Tags: sql, sql-server

In DB1 I have TABLE1 which has 2 years of data.
In DB2 I have updated Data of DB1.TABLE1.

I need to cross check for what are the months the data is not available in DB1.TABLE1.

I have a common column name EmployeeID in both tables.
Format in which Date is stored is "`yyyy-mm-dd`"

Comment: You mean, compare DB2.Table1 with DB1.table1 and find missing rows in db1,table ??

Comment: Yes Ravi ... :you are right

Comment: In DB2 I have records containing Dates in month "January" which is not there in DB1. So how can I query and find out what are the months which are there in DB2 but not in DB1 ?

Comment: Try something like this:SELECT * FROM DB1.Table1 WHERE <column> NOT IN (
    SELECT <column>  from DB1.Table1
    JOIN DB2.Table1 USING(<column>)
)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39344/how-to-join-two-table-to-get-missing-rows-in-the-second-table This link show how to compare two tables and find missing data, u should use table name with database name here